# Branding is not showing in user site

Tags: branding

Branding is not showing in User site were admin site showing the branding  we are using Jquery file for branding.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Master Page is different for my site.You need to customize your my site master page.

Please refer below link .

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-your-My-Site-master-page-a16c4d51-4284-42f0-a2d6-819289bdc400